# Фильтрация при помощи dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

В `MainCategory` имеется 4 категории.
Я чхочу сделать чтобы данные фильтровались при выборе определенного элемента в `dropdown`. Но не знаю как это сделать.

Вот мой код:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MainCategory", "Category")
```

```
        public ActionResult Shop()
        {
            WebModel wb = new WebModel();
            wb.cashshop = entity.cashshopTbls.ToList();
            return View(wb);
        }
```

Comment: [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-search-by-genre)

Comment: Это по кнопке, а мне нужно без кнопки.